# Is it possible to display Chinese characters if I don't install files for East Asian languages for my English Windows XP?

Tags: internationalization, windows-xp, cjk, asianfonts

As you know, we can install files for East Asian language in Control Panel-->Regional and language options-->Languages tab-->Supplemental language support.

The question is: if I don't install this files (by unchecking the checkbox) for my English Windows XP, does that mean none application on the PC can display Chinese characters properly?

Or, if a app says that it's "UNICODE compatible", does this mean that it can handle the Chinese characters properly even when we don't have East Asian language support on our pc?

*(I don't have the permission to uncheck the checkbox and test it on my own, so I hope I can get an answer from you guys.)*

Any answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an application is operating system dependent, you won't be able to see Chinese characters without adding supplemental language support. But os independent softwares will not be affected by that. So, it completely depends on the softwares you are using.

Comment: Thanks, man. And is it able to figure out whether a app is os dependent or not? If possible, could you please give some examples of os independent softwares?

Comment: It is not that easy to figure out if a software is os dependent or not. But if a software supports multiple operating systems, it should be designed os independent. but some parts of it may still use some os specific features. For example Adobe products run on multiple OSes like MacOS and Windows. And Adobe has their own langauge packs/versions for Chinese and some other langauges. Best way to figure out is installing the software and checking the result i guess. If software supports Chinese and uses its own font rendering system, Chinese characters should appear fine.